# Access Two Types of input using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following code:

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(indx){
```

Currently, this allows access to inputs whose type is text, but what if I want access to inputs whose type="text" and type="password".

How would I set that up?

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), which is just a fancy name for comma-separated selectors (the same you would use in CSS):

```
$('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').each(function(indx){
```